# Не работает sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, sqlite3

При числе 1, должен начислять однёрку в "win", но выдаёт ошибку. Логин и пароль работают

```
import sqlite3
from random import randint

global db
global cu
db = sqlite3.connect('server.db')
cu = db.cursor()

cu.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    login TEXT,
    password TEXT
    win INT
)""")
db.commit()

user_login = input('Ваше имя:')
password_login = input('Ваш пороль:')

cu.execute(f"SELECT login FROM user WHERE login = '{user_login}'")
if cu.fetchone() is None:
    cu.execute(f"INSERT INTO user VALUES(?, ?, ?)", (user_login, password_login, 0))
    db.commit()
    print("Зарегестрировано")
else:
    print(f"Добро пожаловать, {user_login}!")
    number = randint(1,2)
    if number == 1:
        cu.execute(f"UPDATE user SET win = {1} WHERE login = '{user_login}' ")
        print("Вы выйграли")
        db.commit()
    else:
        print("Вы проиграли")

for value in cu.execute("SELECT * FROM user"):
    print(value)
```

Ошибка:

> line 28, in 
> cu.execute(f"UPDATE user SET win = {1} WHERE login = '{user_login}' ")
> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: win

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Вы пропустили запятую после поля password в SQL запросе

**Строки 10-12**

```
    login TEXT,
    password TEXT
    win INT
```

**Замените на**

```
    login TEXT,
    password TEXT,
    win INT
```

Comment: Заменил, но ошибка всё такая же

Comment: Таблица user не создаётся заново, так как у вас прописано условие CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS, чтобы пересоздать таблицу - удалите существующую таблицу с помощью SQL-функции drop, или же просто удалите файл server.db и запустите скрипт заново.